# How to push files to Android SD card in TWRP recovery

Tags: boot, android, sd-card

I have a Samsung Galaxy SIII(S3) GT-I9300, rooted and with the latest TWRP recovery.

I did not think of making a backup on the micro sdcard. When I transferred the second ROM and GAPPS, I deleted the current OS.

I can now only boot to recovery. How can I push a new custom ROM and GAPPS from my laptop to the microSD card to flash it in recovery and get any working OS?

On the laptop I use Ubuntu MATE 16.04.3. I have mtp and adb. When I boot to recovey and plug in a device on terminal I see

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
4df1fe8420e94f53    recovery
```

I'm a beginner in Linux, so I don't know what to do next.

Comment: The place to ask about rooting and mooding Android is XDA-Developers, not here. https://forum.xda-developers.com/

Comment: Why use ADB for this? TWRP can mount the SD card and it will connect to the PC like normal, then just copy the files to the SD card. Look in the `mount` section of TWRP.

Answer (score 0):

Download thee ROM file and GAPPs for your phone
copy the files to an sd card
insert the card into your phone
boot the phone into recovery
go to install
select the rom file
and flash it(swipe to flash)
same with the GAPPs